Will a Palm tree on Mars be approximately 2.5 times taller than the same tree on Earth?
I am interested in the growth of plants on different planets. I have read on this site that a 100-pound person will weigh 38 pounds on Mars. Therefore, the ratio of acceleration due to gravity ($g$) on Mars to that on Earth is 0.38.
Now, from the conservation of kinetic and potential energy, we know that
$$(1/2)m*v^2 = mgh -\text{Equation 1}$$
where $m$ is the mass of the body,
$v$ is the initial velocity of the body which is thrown vertically upwards and
$h$ is the maximum height that the body would rise and then start falling down
Assume that a water particle at the plant's root has same energy on Mars as on Earth, and this could allow us to write the following:
Maximum height that water can travel on an Earth plant = $h_\rm{Earth}$ = $v^2/2g_\rm{Earth}$ — Equation 2
Maximum height that water can go on a Mars plant = $h_\rm{Mars}$ = $v^2/2g_\rm{Mars}$ — Equation 3
Divide Eqn (3) by Eqn (2), giving
$$h_\rm{Mars}/h_\rm{Earth} = g_\rm{Earth}/g_\rm{Mars} = 1/0.38 \approx 2.5$$
I understand that a plant uses the process of osmosis to transfer nutrients. I would appreciate your comments/corrections to my analysis.

Is this question specific to Palm trees, or trees? Palms are a somewhat atypical plant that have a fixed starting diameter and then grow fronds upwards, meaning on earth they tend to height limited by mechanical strength rather than flow upwards. Might also be helpful to clarify if this plant is growing indoors under earth normal pressure and light, or somehow outside in near vacuum and cold.

There are multiple things wrong with this question. Tree roots do not shoot water upward. The leaves instead pull water upward via water evaporating from the leaves, thereby creating negative pressure. Water slowly climbs from the roots to the leaves via capillary action rather than a magical pump in the roots.

My question was for plants in general; not specific to Palm tree.  I understand that there is no pump in the plant's root system.  Woody's answer is very helpful. Thanks to all members.

Answer: No
Plants use osmotic pressure  to transport water and nutrients, but this is not what determines the height limit for terrestrial plants.
Transport of water in vascular plants is largely due to turgor pressure (similar to osmotic pressure).  See   https://nph.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/nph.18683 for a detailed discussion.
Turgor pressure is generated because solutes are more concentrated inside plant cells than outside the cells' membrane. Osmotic pressure drives water into the cells, creating turgor pressure which pushes the flexible semi-permeable cell membrane against the rigid cell wall. It is this turgor pressure which pushes water up the vascular channels to the top of  plants and also provides pressure for roots to separate rocks. Pressure of up to 2.0Mpa (290psi or 670ft of water) can be generated https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turgor_pressure
But the tallest Earth plants are only half the height of the turgor pressure. This means turgor pressure is not the sole limiting factor for maximum plant height on Earth.
Turgor pressure is more than enough to transport water to the top of the tallest redwood. The height of palm trees (as specified in the OP) is nowhere near this height, so their growth must be limited by other factors. These other factors may very well limit their height even if they were grown on a planet with lower gravity.
On a planet with 1/3 the gravity of Earth, turgor pressure could potentially transport water and nutrients three times as high. Of course, Earth plants cannot grow on Mars for a multitude of reasons. But if plant life evolved on a low-gravity planet, it could very well produce plants taller than Earth’s.
It is interesting that the tallest trees on Earth (Eucalyptus and Redwoods) are much shorter than the limit imposed by turgor pressure. Height imposes evolutionary costs, so that higher is not necessarily a selective advantage.
There is an analogy with building height. Tall buildings spend disproportionately on elevator shaft volume. Once a building is over about 50 stories, adding more floors does not add useful floor area. Skyscrapers are an exercise in vanity. https://www.economist.com/interactive/culture/2024/09/20/what-supertall-skyscrapers-reveal-about-countries-that-build-them

I think skyscrapers are pretty cool

"R2, activate elevator 31174."

The issue with the space required for elevators is a solved problem that doesn’t make extra tall skyscrapers pointless. When you have long elevators, they are more like trains with their tracks turned 90 degrees. So in a really tall building, you would have your express t̶r̶a̶i̶n̶ elevator and the local ones. Each floor is like a train stop so local elevators can go to the side to allow the express elevators to stop at only every maybe tens floors or more. Having elevators like trains in tall buildings is a solution to the space problem and I think that there are others as well.

@TheRocketfan Extra tall skyscrapers are usually not pointless because they deliberately add antenna or spires or other things for extra height - and those things have a physical point at the top.

There's also the matter of competition.  The tallest trees tend to be taller because they're in densely forested areas, where they are literally competing with other trees to get the most access to sunlight.  A lone palm tree has no evolutionary drive to grow taller, and in fact has every reason not to, regardless of whether the lower gravity would make it easier.

The idea of an elevator limit was based in the concept of an industrial-age office building where everyone came in at 9 am and left at 6 pm. Modern mixed-use supertalls with staggered shafts or two-tier systems have stayed in ~the same elevator space budget as older buildings half as tall.

@TheRocketfan There are also a few other things that need to be delivered upwards for such as water and electricity.  Any water capacity that is delivered to upper floors must be accounted for in the floors below it.

@manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact lol, reading it in a literal sense, it has a totally different meaning.

@JimmyJames And HVAC as well. Traditional systems using huge chillers or other equipment in the basement and/or on the roof need to be more distributed for a tall building. With modern heat pumps that is less of an problem, but still complicates things.
